# How ConcurrenthashMap manages if Concurrency level is HIGHER than the number of Buckets?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

The `ConcurrentHashMap` uses *segment level locking* mechanism for supporting concurrent modifications. It has three basic parameters

- Number of Buckets. (Default initial size = 16)
- Concurrency Level. (Default size = 16)
- Load Factor.(Default size = 0.75)

In default case we have *Single Lock per Bucket*. If the number of buckets are made as 32 then we will have *Single Lock per Two Buckets*.

How is it managed if number of buckets are **Less** than the Concurrency Level, i.e. if

```
Map cMap = new ConcurrentHashMap(16,1,32);
```

Usually a bucket uses a Collection (Linked List) for the items with Hash-codes colliding in same bucket. Do we have in above case Two Locks per Bucket, if yes then how it is managed, (does half of the collection in a bucket uses one lock and other half uses second lock ?)

I have searched and was able to see the answers if the `ConcurrentHashMap` is resized to have more buckets than the number of Locks but I was not able to get an answer what if it was the reverse case, i.e :

How ConcurrenthashMap manages if Concurrency level is HIGHER than the number of Buckets ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cfloat%2Cint%29) in the constructor should answer your question:

```
if (initialCapacity < concurrencyLevel)   // Use at least as many bins
    initialCapacity = concurrencyLevel;   // as estimated threads
```

See also the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap-int-float-int-):

> **concurrencyLevel** the estimated number of concurrently updating threads. The implementation may use this value as a sizing hint.

Comment: I got to learn the internals of  `ConcurrentHashMap`. Thanks.